# Zoom Image Woocommerce - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wordpress 3.8, woocommerce 2.0.20. And im using this Zoom Image Plugin(http://wordpress.org/plugins/zoom-image/)

Everything is looking fine, but when I have a product with color variation, it does not change the color of the image, but when you put your mouse to zoom, it appears the previous image.

Zoom Image Plugin code:

```
class TccZoom {
    var $pluginPath;
    var $pluginUrl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Set Plugin Path
        $this->pluginPath = dirname(__FILE__);

        // Set Plugin URL
        $this->pluginUrl = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/zoom-image';



        add_filter('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', array( &$this, 'apply_zoom') );
        add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', array( &$this, 'add_scripts') );

        if(is_admin()){
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_zoom_image_plugin_page'));
            add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'zoom_image_init'));

            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts',  array(&$this, 'wp_enqueue_color_picker') );
        }
    }

    static function install() {
        add_option('zoom_image_options', array('zoom_thumbnails'=>'1'));    
    }

    function wp_enqueue_color_picker( ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker-script', plugins_url('/js/colorPicker.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
    }   

    public function add_zoom_image_plugin_page(){
        // This page will be under "Settings"
    add_options_page('Zoom Image Settings', 'Zoom Image', 'manage_options', 'zoom-image', array($this, 'create_zoom_image_page'));
    }

    public function create_zoom_image_page(){
        ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2>Zoom Image Settings</h2>        
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                    // This prints out all hidden setting fields
            settings_fields('zoom_image_group');    
            do_settings_sections('zoom_image_settings');
        ?>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    }

    public function zoom_image_init(){      

        register_setting('zoom_image_group', 'zoom_image_options', array($this, 'check_zoom_image_options'));

        add_settings_section(
        'general_zoom_settings',
        'Zoom image options',
        array($this, 'print_section_info'),
        'zoom_image_settings'
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'zoom_thumbnails', 
            'Zoom over thumbnails ?', 
            array($this, 'create_zoom_thumbnails_field'), 
            'zoom_image_settings',
            'general_zoom_settings'         
        );      
        /*
        add_settings_field(
            'zoom_level', 
            'Zoom level', 
            array($this, 'create_zoom_level_field'), 
            'zoom_image_settings',
            'general_zoom_settings'         
        );      
        */
        add_settings_field(
            'zoom_type', 
            'Zoom type', 
            array($this, 'create_zoom_inner_field'), 
            'zoom_image_settings',
            'general_zoom_settings'         
        );      
        /*
        add_settings_field(
            'zoom_background_color', 
            'Background color', 
            array($this, 'create_zoom_color_field'), 
            'zoom_image_settings',
            'general_zoom_settings'         
        );      
        */


    }

    public function check_zoom_image_options($input){

        if(!in_array($input['zoom_thumbnails'],array(0,1)))
        {
            $input['zoom_thumbnails'] = '';
        }

        if(!in_array($input['zoom_level'],array(0.5,1,2)))
        {
            $input['zoom_level'] = '';
        }

        if(!in_array($input['zoom_type'],array('window','inner','lens')))
        {
            $input['zoom_type'] = '';
        }

        return $input;

    }

    public function print_section_info(){
    //print 'Enter your setting below:';
    }

    public function create_zoom_thumbnails_field(){

        $options =  get_option('zoom_image_options');
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" id="zoom_over_thumbnails" name="zoom_image_options[zoom_thumbnails]" value="1" <?php if($options['zoom_thumbnails']==1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />

    <?php
    }

    public function create_zoom_inner_field(){

        $options =  get_option('zoom_image_options');
    ?>

        <select name="zoom_image_options[zoom_type]">
            <option value="window" <?php if($options['zoom_type']=='window') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Window</option>
            <option value="lens" <?php if($options['zoom_type']=='lens') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Lens</option>
            <option value="inner" <?php if($options['zoom_type']=='inner') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Inner</option>
        </select>

    <?php
    }


    public function create_zoom_level_field()
    {
        $options =  get_option('zoom_image_options');
    ?>
        <select name="zoom_image_options[zoom_level]">
            <option value="1" <?php if($options['zoom_level']==1) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Normal zoom</option>
            <?php /*
            <option value="0.5" <?php if($options['zoom_level']==0.5) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Twice as big</option>
            */ ?>
            <option value="2" <?php if($options['zoom_level']==2) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Twice as small</option>
        </select>
    <?php
    }


    public function create_zoom_color_field()
    {
        $options =  get_option('zoom_image_options');
    ?>  
        <input type="text" id="zoom_background" class="wp-color-picker-field" name="zoom_image_options[zoom_background_color]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($options['zoom_background_color']); ?>" />
        <br />
        <span>Available only for Zoom type: window</span>
    <?php    
    }

    function apply_zoom()
    {


        global $post;
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full', false, '' );

        $options = get_option('zoom_image_options');

        ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('data-zoom-image','<?php echo $src[0]; ?>');
        $('.woocommerce-main-image img').elevateZoom({
            <?php if($options['zoom_level']) { ?>
            zoomLevel : <?php echo strip_tags(trim($options['zoom_level'])); ?>,
            <?php }else { ?>
            zoomLevel : 1,
            <?php } ?>

            <?php
            switch ($options['zoom_type'])
            {
                case "window":
            ?>
            zoomType  : "window",   
            lensShape : "square",   
            <?php   
                break;  
                case "lens":
            ?>
             zoomType   : "lens",
             lensShape : "round",

            <?php   
                break;  
                case "inner":
            ?>
            zoomType : "inner",
            cursor : "crosshair",
            <?php   
                break;  
                default:
            ?>
            zoomType  : "window",   
            lensShape : "square",   
            <?php   
                break;
            }

                if(strlen(trim($options['zoom_background_color']))>1 && $options['zoom_type']=='window' ) { 
            ?>
                tint:true, 
                tintColour:'<?php echo esc_attr($options['zoom_background_color']); ?>', 
                tintOpacity:0.5
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        });

        <?php if($options['zoom_thumbnails']==1) { ?>
        $('.thumbnails .zoom img').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('data-zoom-image',$(this).parent().attr('href'));
        });
        $('.thumbnails .zoom img').elevateZoom({
            zoomType  : "window",
            lensShape : "square",
            lensSize  : 20,
            zoomWindowPosition: 16, 
            zoomWindowOffetx: 10,
            <?php if($options['zoom_level']) { ?>
            zoomLevel : <?php echo strip_tags(trim($options['zoom_level'])); ?>,
            <?php }else { ?>
            zoomLevel : 1,
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
                if(strlen(trim($options['zoom_background_color']))>1) { 
            ?>
                tint:true, 
                tintColour:'<?php echo esc_attr($options['zoom_background_color']); ?>', 
                tintOpacity:0.5
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        });
        <?php } ?>

    })
    </script>
    <?php   
        echo ob_get_clean();
    }

    function add_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tcc-magnifier-js', $this->pluginUrl.'/js/jquery.elevateZoom-2.5.5.min.js', 'jquery' );
    }




}
$tcczoom = new TccZoom;
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('TccZoom', 'install') );
```

Comment: Is this just the plugin code copied, or have you actually tried something yourself?

Comment: Just the plugin copied!

Answer (score 0):

We use something very similar, [CloudZoom for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloud-zoom-for-woocommerce/), which has the same problem as well. If you are interested in switching plugins, you can solve the same problem for that plugin by adding this line of jQuery to a script in your header:

`jQuery('form.variations_form').on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
    addCloudZoom($productImages);
} );`

Again, just to be clear, this solution won't work for the plugin you are using, but it solves the same problem for a plugin that provides identical functionality. If you can't find a solution for the plugin you're using, you might try switching and using this solution.